# Making blogger navigation buttons stretch to fill page width

Tags: html, css, navigation, width, blogger

I am working on refining a blog for a friend,
The thing she really wants is to have the navigation buttons on top of the page stretch until they fill up the whole page width, I have seen some generic answers. Those did seem to work on other websites, and plain html files, but they dont seem to work with blogger. It would be great is someone could help me,

Comment: We can't really help you unless we see some code. What solutions have you tried so far?

Comment: @HunterTurner2 I have tried to just remove the width, set padding to percentages, and also i'm not totally clear what part of the blogger code refers to the buttons... and the blogger code is way to big to post, does anyone know what part of the blogger code i need to use?